# how to define "Current price crosses above Ema"...?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

ema1 =ta.ema(close, 14)
price1 =input.price(defval=0)

plot(ema1, color=color.new(color.red, 14), linewidth=2, offset=2)
plot(price1)

longCondition = ta.crossover(input.price(defval=0), ta.ema(close, 14))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(input.price(defval=0), ta.ema(close, 14))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in variable `close` refers to current price in real time. You can see that on your chart if you hover your mouse over the last bar and check the close price.